# Declare object with keys constrained to be element of object literal

Tags: typescript

Suppose I have a literal type defined as:

```
type MyKeys = 'a' | 'b' | 'c' | 'd'
```

I'd like to declare a mapped type similar to `Record<MyKeys, number>`, except I only want to have to fill in a subset of my keys. (In reality, the literal has ~20 values).

I'd like to avoid `Partial` because it allows a potential value to be specified as undefined. I'd like to help developers ensure that if they define a value, it's specified. This also helps when dealing with doing `Object.entries`, because it gets rid of handling undefined for the values.

The scenario here is that we have a variety of plugins that require configuration, but do not require all fields. So something like:

```
// Use another type instead of Partial<Record<...>>
type ConfigType = Partial<Record<MyKeys, number>>

const PluginA: ConfigType = {
  a: undefined, // Would be legal with Partial, but I'd like to block this
  b: 25
};

const PluginB: ConfigType = {
  c: 13,
  d: 52,
};

const PluginC: ConfigType = {
  a: 12,
  d: 42,
};
```

Comment: If you had a few members only, this could be possible by generating a union of all possible allowed combinations, but frankly 20 or so is going to prevent this from fruition. I don't think this is possible but you can write a helper function to infer this for you.

Comment: Yeah, that was my first thought before I realized I'd have like 15 objects with 20 properties, mostly unused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like my comment hints at, you can't really make a feasible solution so you can type it like this and have it validate it correctly:

```
const conf: ConfType = { ... };
```

But what you can do is have a function to do that for you:

```
const conf = checked({ ... }); // errors at COMPILE TIME if invalid
```

Let's see how we can do this:

```
type ConfInvalidError = [{ error: "Cannot pass undefined." }];

type ValidConf<C> = C extends Partial<Record<MyKeys, number>> ? undefined extends C[keyof C] ? ConfInvalidError : C : ConfInvalidError;

function checked<C>(conf: ValidConf<C>): C { return conf as C; }
```

TypeScript will infer `C`, then pass it to `ValidConf`.

In `ValidConf`, we check if it's a valid config object. If it extends `Partial<Record<MyKeys, number>>`, and doesn't include `undefined` in the values, then it will give back `C`, otherwise it gives a helpful error message.

Test this solution out in the playground below:

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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)